# C# Data Request Queue with Bundling

Tags: c#, .net, queue

**Background**

I have an application that acts as an interface between an external API and my database, constantly making API requests and storing the responses in a database.

Let's say this API has an endpoint with a user(s) parameter, accepting either a single user or multiple.  My application may require, over some period of time, data for multiple different users.  This API is rate-limited by requests per minute, and a block request for multiple users only counts once.

**Problem**

My application can get to a point where I need the information on say 100 different users, but I don't know that I need exactly this 100 at any one time.  Because of this, I'm hitting the rate limit of the API.  My application is basically querying the API for user data one-by-one.

**Solution Needed**

Is there a good way to throw each of these independent requests into some queue, where once the queue hits x number of requests or after a certain amount of time, bundles all the requests together into a single API query, and then informs each caller that the data is ready?

Let's just say I have a Windows Form app with a text input for user id and a button to submit the user id to the API interface, as an async function.  Instead of querying the API for each button push, I'd like to group together each requests until either the count hits say 100+ or a certain amount of time has passed.

Comment: Bit unsure of a few things: 1) Why is there an API rate limit? 2) Why could you end up making 100+ requests at one time? 3) What is it you're trying to do in the first place, and what are you trying to achieve? I know you're saying you want some kind of queue - but what I'm asking is what is the higher level problem you're experiencing?

Comment: @GeoffJames 1) I don't control the API. 2) This is a service that feeds data to an application run in multiple instances, so each instance of the application may be requesting different data at different times, and I need to do my best to bundle those requests. 3) I'm basically running a reporting tool that relies upon some internal and some external information.  I need to keep the external information (from the API) up-to-date and they don't have any sort of webhooks that I can subscribe to yet.

Comment: @DanielABurke - thanks for that. It makes sense what you're asking - I just wanted to see what problem you were trying to solve. It's late, and my brain isn't functioning properly; but, let's say that you do have some sort of cache/queue system - how are you going to assert and distinguish when to cut off queuing? Are you going to have one last call that has a "go" parameter to tell the API to aggregate all the queue requests? I could be missing the point. *edit - just re-read, and saw that you would use `x` number of requests or time etc.*

Comment: @DanielABurke - so, in short: I'm guessing you're asking *how to build a queue/cache system*?

Comment: @GeoffJames well, yes, but with the ability to bundle I guess?

Comment: @DanielABurke - then, I'd just suggest building a queue/cache of all the requests, then when you want to aggregate them, just pass them to a function that can turn them into one big long request with however many parameters, or an array (or similar) of parameters etc. - that you then pass to your single query. As to the "informing each caller that the data is ready" - not sure off the top of my head. Is the queuing going to be done in the WinForms app, or separately? If it's in WinForms - you could use some kind of callback or pub/sub eventing; if it's not, then I'm not sure.

Comment: @GeoffJames I ended up implementing a sort of multi-threaded queue system, where the queue handler runs on its own thread.  I use methods to add API requests to this queue through a custom class, and then watch a status property on this custom class through an async method.  When the status is changed, I know the queue has processed the request.  The queue itself serves up requests in order received, but is also smart enough to group similar requests together to save on the rate limit.  Appreciate your help!  Not sure what's customary here, but do I just delete my question or answer it myself?

Comment: @DanielABurke - glad to hear you've managed to solve your problem. You can do one of a few things. I would consider either: answer your own question, if you feel the issue you had, and the answer itself would be useful to other users in the future; or, if you're satisfied the solution is business-specific (as such) and might not prove so useful to others, you could consider deleting it. Entirely up to you. Happy to help, either way! :)